# Adding "before_body" for Wordpress Sidebars?

Tags: php, wordpress

Wordpress can do this:

```
function _tk_widgets_init() {
    register_sidebar( array(
        'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', '_tk' ),
        'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
        'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
        'after_widget'  => '</aside>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>',
    ) );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', '_tk_widgets_init' );
```

This would produce something like this:

```
<aside>
    <h3></h3>
    BODY 
</aside>
```

What I need to be able to do is end up with:

```
<aside>
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="anotherBlock">BODY</div>
</aside>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it usig what was already there:

```
register_sidebar( array(
    'name'          => __( 'Sidebar', '_tk' ),
    'id'            => 'sidebar-1',
    'before_widget' => '<aside id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'before_title'  => '<h3 class="widget-title">',
    'after_title'   => '</h3><div class="mainWidgetBody">',
    'after_widget'  => '</div></aside>',


) );
```